# Ambiguous behavior of signInWithEmailAndPassword method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an activity namely *EmailSignUpActivity* from where I am creating a user by leveraging `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method from Firebase. After creating a user I am redirecting him to the *MainActivity* where `signOut` method is present. After signing out I am redirecting the user to the *LoginActivity* where email and password login option is present and signing in the user using `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method.

My problem is that after creating a user for the first time I am signing out the user and again logging in the user immediately in the *LoginActivity* but none of my log tags which are written inside `signInWithEmailAndPassword` are working neither the progress dialog is getting dismissed which is written inside the `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, which shows that this method is not getting called. But when I clear my app from the phone's memory and opening it again then the *MainActivity* is opening up which was supposed to open up after a successful *sign in*.

Moreover, when I clear the app from the phone's memory after creating a new user and signing him out and then if I try to log in the user then everything is working fine.

Could anyone explain the reason for this ambiguous behavior?

In **EmailSignUpActivity** *creating the user*

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: new user created");
                            Toast.makeText(EmailSignUpActivity.this, "User created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            Log.w(TAG, "onFailure: user creation failed  ", e);
                            Toast.makeText(EmailSignUpActivity.this, "User already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

In **LoginActivity** *signing in the user*

```
private void emailAndPasswordLogin() {

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick:");

            progressDialog.show();

            String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

            if(!email.equals("null") && !password.equals("null")) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: mAuth ==> "+mAuth);

                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete:");

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: if task successful");

                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: login success ");

                            Boolean newUser = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();

                            Log.d(TAG, "LoginButton == onSuccess: newUser ==> "+newUser);

                            if(newUser){

                                //
                                boolean hasImage = false;
                                enteringDataIntoUserNode(hasImage);

                                //
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);


                            }else{
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }else{
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            Log.w(TAG, "onFailure: login failure ", task.getException());

                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Email or Password invalid.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        }
    });
}
```

In **MainActivity** *signing out the user*

```
 private void signOut() {

    //  getting the provider id
    String providerId = null;

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Provider: " + profile.getProviderId());

        providerId = profile.getProviderId();
    }

    if(providerId.equals("password")){
        Log.d(TAG, "signOut: inside password sign out");
        // firebase sign out

        firebaseAuth.signOut();

        Log.d(TAG, "signOut: currentUser ==> "+firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser());

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginAndSignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this dont initialize the provider, and when you want to sign out dont get the current user but use `this` instead. ONLY if you are using firebase UI.

`String providerId = profile.getProviderId()`;

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(this)`;

if you are using Firebase Auth, maybe try and Catch to see if your Firebase is logging out in the first place not only switching Intents. I remember i had the same problem and it was regarding my logging out process maybe something like this:

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
try {
 mAuth.signOut();
 Toast.makeText(this, "User Sign out!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch (Exception e) {
 Log.e(TAG, "onClick: Exception "+e.getMessage(),e );
}
```

Comment: `signOut()` don't take any arguments so passing `this` is impossible.

Comment: Sorry about that it is possible just not in your case, check the editted answer and tell me if it helps.